# Как в коде прописать возвращение на домашнюю страницу?(с помощью Selenium driver)

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation

В селениумe есть метод, который позволяет перейти по адресу на определенную страницу `driver.get("google.com");` Хочу осуществить следующие действия: браузер переходит на `google.com`, потом откатывается на домашнюю страницу, а после вновь возвращается в гугл. Первый и 3ий шаги реализуются методом,который я привел выше, а как реализовать возврат? Именно не как переход с помощью того же метода `get`, а как если бы была нажата кнопка "назад" в браузере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашей задачи необходимо использовать следующий код

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

Так же есть другие методы в интерфейсе [Navigate](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Navigation.html)